# Use auto_increment value in INSERT

Tags: mysql

What actually I am trying to do is, insert a row with `INSERT INTO table (col2, col3, <...>) VALUES (col1, $something, <...>).`

col1 is an auto_increment id column, and basically I want to copy that value to col2 on INSERT statement, within **one** query. Is this possible?

Comment: Why? Just why would you want to do something like that? I am very curious about the reason why?

Comment: @AgeDeo It's about displaying the rows in the correct order (that's how my code works and yes, it has to do with performance). That's not what I asked though is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correct then in the same `INSERT` statement you are trying to insert the generated `AUTO_INCREMENT` ID to another column.

Well, that's not possible IMO; cause if you do so the `AUTO_INCREMENT` ID is still not generated.

One solution is to use a stored procedure and perform the `INSERT+UPDATE` together like below (a sample)

```
create procedure usp_dowork(parameter list ...)
as
begin
INSERT INTO table (col2, col3, <...>) VALUES (NULL, $something, <...>);
update table set col2 = LAST_INSERT_ID()
where col1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
end
```

You should consider using a transaction block around the DML's to make sure both the operations happens successfully.

Comment: Sadly this is not what I'm looking for. Can you suggest any other way?

Comment: @user2354308, AFAIK, there is no other possible way.

Comment: I think it's not possible to update the newly inserted row using an AFTER INSERT TRIGGER, at least not in MySQL

Comment: Any way to do it in two queries without the possible mistakes due to many fast requests?

Comment: could you lock the table and use the last_insert_id() function on the second update

Comment: @user2354308, see edit in answer if that helps. You can use a proc and perform insert + update.